# Making counter beside the icon like facebook

Tags: html, css, counter

If you see the "notifications" icon on facebook, when you have a new notification, or more, it will display how many(number) besides it with a red background.

How can I make something like this?

i want to apply this on http://jsfiddle.net/uckZp/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook uses an API call to query the database to find out and return this number. If you want to do this specifically for facebook then look here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

If you wanted to make something similar for your own site then you will need a database and a load of server side code.

**EDIT**

How's this - http://jsfiddle.net/uckZp/1/

Comment: I would like to know the design behind this not how they get the number. How you can make it in css so a number is besides the icon, with a background and so

Comment: Edited it again to have a bit more "standout" of a look. http://jsfiddle.net/uckZp/3/